# The bot doesn't understand the value when I use the property Describe

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, formflow

I am using the sample "SandwichOrder" code. When I use the property "Describe" to change the item value the bot doesn't understand the setted value.

```
public enum LengthOptions
{
    [Describe("Test 1")]
    SixInch = 1,

    [Describe("Test 2")]
    FootLong = 2
};
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the bot doesn't like the space in your value? As it said `"Test" is not an option`

Comment: Consider using `[Terms]` decoration

Answer (score 1):

It's the problem how `FormFlow` handles the feedback after user's selection, the result is actually right the type of `LengthOptions`. Since we're not able to modify the source code of `BotBuilder SDK`, here is a workaround to solve this problem: we try to override the feedback of this item in `FormFlow`, and here is the code when building the `FormDialog`:

```cs
...
.Field(nameof(Length),
    validate: async (state, response) =>
     {
         var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = response };
         var value = (LengthOptions)response;
         result.Feedback = "Your selection means " + value;
         return result;
     })
...
```

The `Length` property in above code can be defined like this:

```cs
public enum LengthOptions
{
    [Describe("Test 1")]
    SixInch = 1,

    [Describe("Test 2")]
    FootLong = 2
};

public LengthOptions? Length { get; set; }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What @Grace Feng mentioned is one way to do that. Another simpler way would be to add the `Terms` decoration to `LengthOptions` each item.

So the code would be :

```
public enum LengthOptions
    {
        [Terms(new string[] { "Test 1" })]
        [Describe("Test 1")]
        SixInch = 1,

        [Terms(new string[] { "Test 2" })]
        [Describe("Test 2")]
        FootLong = 2
    };
```

Now your bot will automatically understand the value of "Test 1" as SixInch and "Test 2" as FootLong